# Yii 1.1 urlManager .php?param=<param> redirect

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii1.x, yii-url-manager

I'm having issues figuring out how to process some old URLs in Yii 1.1 that currently return 404. 
Below a small bit of the config file.

```
 'urlManager' => array(
        'class' => 'UrlManager',
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            '/' => '/site/index',
            '/niche.php?slug=<slug>' => '/videos?niche=<slug>',
         ),
  ),
```

the first rule works fine, second one however, i can't quite figure out how to write properly. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't write it properly - rules are used for friendly URLs, and `/niche.php?slug=something` is not friendly URL, it will not be processed by rules. You should probably use `.htaccess` redirections or create `niche.php` file with redirection.

Comment: thans @rob006 i will look into that. i had a feeling about this, but wasn't 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a kind of redirecting...

Here is a possible solution:

1. Create the file CBeginRequest.php in protected/components

```
class CBeginRequest {

    public static function run($event /* CEvent */) {
        $uri = strtolower($event->sender->request->requestUri);
        $par = parse_url($uri);
        if (isset($par['path']) && isset($par['query'])) {
            if ($par['path'] == '/niche.php') {
                parse_str($par['query'], $get);
                $niche = isset($get['slug']) ? $get['slug'] : '';
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->redirect('/videos?niche='.$niche);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2. Add the line to protected/config/config.php:

```
    'onBeginRequest'=>array('CBeginRequest', 'run'),
```